# Is there a free way to import SVGs into a Unity android game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I googled this topic and all I found are pricey assets. Is there a free asset or something that I can use? I need the SVGs for a mobile game I'm developing, are there any reasons why I shouldn't use the vectors instead of raster? The game will be a 2D strategic warfare game, that will not be using extreme graphics, just simplest simbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity is going to add native support for SVG in future builds.
All you need is download "vector graphics" preview package via package manager.
Right now it's in "preview" state.

More information here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/vector-graphics-preview-package.529845/

Comment: Thank you :), will try and ill let you know when i do